# Behavior-Driven Development(BDD) Testing with Fast API python web framework

Tags: python, testing, bdd, fastapi

I want to write BDD test cases for the Fast API framework where I have written some REST API.

Though for normal test cases Fast API mentioned `pytest` package. Basic Code snippet for testing with `pytest` mentioned here also in their official documentation:- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#testing.

We have multiple testing frameworks For python BDD test cases. One such testing framework is [Behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). But Behave as integration support for Flask and Django. I am struggling to figure out the testing framework that can best integrate with the FastAPI framework too.

I am new to FastAPI and any suggestions and help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [pytest-bdd](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-bdd/), it's a plugin for Pytest, since it's already integrated with pytest it works fine and naturally with FastAPI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).